# Junit for Controller class

Tags: junit, controller, mockito, powermockito

I have controller method and for it I am making Junit but getting Null pointer error when it calling a service method. I used power mock but still getting Null pointer.

method:

```
                 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/DSR.do")
public ModelAndView displayDataSourceReportPage(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {
    log.debug(" Inside displayDataSourceReportPage method ");
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        request.setAttribute(MENU_SELECTED, LABEL_MENU_SOURCEDATA);
        request.setAttribute(SUB_MENU_SELECTED, LABEL_SUBMENU_DSR);




        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List dataSource = dataSourceReportService.listDataSourceReportByCurrentRunInd("C");
        map.put("dataSource", dataSource);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return new ModelAndView("DataSourceReport", "model", map);
}
```

test Method:

@InjectMocks 
      private DataSourceReportController dataSourceReportController;

```
@Mock
private DataSourceReportService dataSourceReportServiceImpl;


@InjectMocks
private DataSourceReportDAO dataSourceReportDAO = new DataSourceReportDAOImpl();
@Before
public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
@Test
public void testdisplayDataSourceReportPage() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(DataSourceReport.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(HttpServletRequest.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Model.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(DataSourceReportService.class);

    HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    Model model = Mockito.mock(Model.class);
    dataSourceReportServiceImpl = PowerMockito.mock(DataSourceReportService.class);

    DataSourceReport dataSourceReport = PowerMockito.mock(DataSourceReport.class);
    dataSourceReport.setCurrentRunInd("abc");
    dataSourceReport.setActualFileName("Somthing");
    dataSourceReport.setFileCountId(3);
    dataSourceReport.setFileId(4);
    dataSourceReport.setRecCount(3);
    List<DataSourceReport> list = new ArrayList<DataSourceReport>();
    list.add(dataSourceReport);
    String currentRunInd = "currentRunInd";
    Object obj =getClass();



    PowerMockito.when(dataSourceReportDAO.listDataSourceReportByCurrentRunInd(currentRunInd)).thenReturn(list);


    DataSourceReportController ctrl = new DataSourceReportController();
    ctrl.displayDataSourceReportPage(request, model);

}
```

getting Null at "dataSourceReportService.listDataSourceReportByCurrentRunInd("C");"

Comment: I cannot figure out what are you doing? According to code you mock service class, but you the DAO for when. Farther, you use service class in controller. However in test you create controller via `new` and don't set service. How it would work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this in the test class

```
PowerMockito.when(dataSourceReportService.listDataSourceReportByCurrentRunInd("C")).thenReturn(list);
```

before calling

```
ctrl.displayDataSourceReportPage(request, model);
```

Comment: I tried PowerMockito.when(dataSourceReportService.listDataSourceReportByCurrentRunInd("C")).thenReturn(list); but this is not working seems that Power mock is able to mock the Service class. I have used @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DataSourceReportService.class})

Comment: Update your class and test class with what you currently have in your work space  exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ Arthur Zagretdinov

I tried the below code and it worked.

```
            private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest req;

    @Mock
    private DataSourceReportService dataSourceReportServiceImpl;

    @InjectMocks
    private DataSourceReportController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }
 @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

@Test
public void testdisplayDataSourceReportPage() throws Exception {

    HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    Model model = Mockito.mock(Model.class);

    DataSourceReport dataSourceReport =Mockito.mock(DataSourceReport.class);;
    dataSourceReport.setCurrentRunInd("abc");
    dataSourceReport.setActualFileName("Somthing");
    dataSourceReport.setFileCountId(3);
    dataSourceReport.setFileId(4);
    dataSourceReport.setRecCount(3);
    List<DataSourceReport> list = new ArrayList<DataSourceReport>();
    list.add(dataSourceReport);
    ModelAndView modelView = controller.displayDataSourceReportPage(request, model);
    modelView.addObject(dataSourceReport);

}
```